# Canonical transformation, Lagrangian submanifold and generating function

Tags: manifolds, generating-functions, mathematical-physics, hamilton-jacobi-equation, canonical-transformation

If we know a generating function $\phi$ for a canonical transformation and also we know a generating function W for a Lagrangian submanifold $\Lambda$, what is a generating function for $\phi(\Lambda)$?

Comment: Why are you shouting?

Answer (score 0):

You can find an answer in the paper by Brunella $\textit{On a Theorem of Sikorav}$,
Enseign. Math. (2) 37, No. 1--2, 83--87 (1991; Zbl 0739.58015). Lemma 4 is the result you are looking for, and you can find the paper [here](https://www.e-periodica.ch/cntmng?pid=ens-001:1991:37::47). Note that however there is the hypothesis that the symplectomorphism is compactly supported, and I do not know a reference where it is removed (nor if in fact the result is still true).